# ATM Admin Panel System in Python

Tags: python

I have set up admin in the bank system and I want to add and remove users, but I can't. How can i do it?

```
def adminmenu():
    print("--- Admin Menu ---")
    adminprocess = input(" Please enter a number of the settings operations supported: \n1. Add User\n2. Remove User\n3. Display all Users\n4. Exit Admin Menu\n>>>")
    if adminprocess == "3":
        print()
    if adminprocess == "4":
        return entry()
```

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok ok ok ok ok ok.